# What is the best way to slowly (500/second) update many documents in a MongoDB database with a new field and value?

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I have a MongoDB database that I want to update about 100,000 documents with a "score" for each on a daily basis. The challenge with the way I have implemented it is that it tries to update them really really fast (about 2,000 updates per second) and my MongoDB limits are set to only 500 updates per second (M5 tier) so MongoDB is sporadically throwing an error back to me (I confirmed with MongoDB support that this why I'm getting the error sometimes).

Is there a way to perhaps batch the updates or a better way to do what I'm doing?

Here's the code I am using. If I just turn it off when I get an error and start it back up it will eventually update all the documents, but that's an unsustainable solution:

```
await client
  .db("test")
  .collection("collection_name")
  .find({ score: { $exists: false } })
  .forEach(async data => {
    await client
      .db("test")
      .collection("collection_name")
      .updateOne(
        { _id: data._id },
        {
          $set: {
            score: GetScore(data)
          }
        }
      );
  });
client.close();
```

Comment: Do you use async.js library in node.js ? If so you can limit to a number from an array !!

Comment: @whoami mind sending a link to the library? I want to make sure I'm looking at the right one.

Comment: Check this :: https://www.npmjs.com/package/async , Since you're using `async-await` I wouldn't recommend going that route instead you can actually write logic for control flow in your code..

Comment: @whoami thanks, I'll dig into this. 27.5M downloads this week means I should definitely know this package :)

Comment: What  `GetScore(data)` does? Can we perform native MongoDB update, so you don't need perform `updateOne` several times...

Comment: @mpc75 : It's a lot more powerful package with callbacks & before `async-awaits`, But with `async-awaits`/`promises` you could check this :: https://www.npmjs.com/package/co !! Anyway I wouldn't prefer both though they've very good func's to handle flows, my suggestion is if a small piece of logic that can be handled well using native .Js go for it :-)

Comment: @Valijon thanks for your suggestion. I am still new to MongoDB so am not 100% sure what you mean by "perform native MongoDB update". Would you mind clarifying; I'd like to learn :) To answer your question, it takes a few data points from within each document and weighs them against an ideal to create a score of that document.

Comment: post please ` GetScore` logic, so we can see if it's possible to be done in [MongoDB way](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.update/#modify-a-field-using-the-values-of-the-other-fields-in-the-document)

Comment: @Valijon thanks for sharing the link that was super helpful and I now understand what you mean by in the MongoDB way. Considering that the GetScore logic pulls from a separate large array of ideals which is external to the document itself and that the logic itself is about 75 lines of code, I think it might be a bit too cumbersome at this time to convert it to the MongoDB way. Thank you for the link and support though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One problem might be that the callback to `forEach` is likely not awaited from the mongo library, therefore multiple of your queries will be issued concurrently - query two will be issued before query one is finished etc.

You could use a combination of `next` and `hasNext` on the cursor combined with awaiting a a promise that resolves later (might not be needed) instead of doing `forEach`, like so:

```
var cursor = await client
  .db("test")
  .collection("collection_name")
  .find({ score: { $exists: false } });
while(await cursor.hasNext()) {
  var data = await cursor.next();
  await client
    .db("test")
    .collection("collection_name")
    .updateOne(
      { _id: data._id },
        {
        $set: {
          score: GetScore(data)
        }
      }
    );
}
```

Docs: http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/3.5/api/Cursor.html#next
http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/3.5/api/Cursor.html#hasNext

Again, the "sleep" might actually not be necessary when you get your queries to run sequentially.

Comment: thank you, this worked without the ```await new Promise``` ! It is now updating at a pace of around 150 documents/second. Before I accept your response as the solution can you please remove the ```await new Promise``` and add ```await``` before ```cursor.hasNext()``` and ```cursor.next()``` , these additional awaits were necessary :)